# Listview to accept Nill value in vba

Tags: excel, vba

While uploading data in listview, if any item has no valuew , it pull next row data. Can we allow to show nill value in listview.

```
Dim Acon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim row                 As Long
With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("V27").Value
    .Open
End With

With Rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = Acon
    .Source = "Select * from OJT where [Created by]='" & username1 & "'"
    .Open
End With

With Rs
    Rs.MoveFirst
    While Not Rs.EOF

        If Rs.Fields("Created by").Value = username1 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ListView14.ListItems.Add , , Rs.Fields("Emp #").Value
            ListView14.ListItems(lv_item).ListSubItems.Add , , Rs.Fields("Name").Value
            ListView14.ListItems(lv_item).ListSubItems.Add , , Rs.Fields("Created by").Value
            lv_item = lv_item + 1
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        Rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End With

Rs.Close
Acon.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Append an empty string to what you have seems like the simplest solution

e.g. `ListView14.ListItems.Add , , Rs.Fields("Emp #").Value & ""`